# Deleting a file that resides on an internal Linux server via my application

Tags: java, javascript, linux, spring, jsp

I've recently been working on an enhancement for an application at work that will allow users to delete presentations stored not on their local machine but on a Linux server present on the internal network.  My problem is that I am not sure how to go about performing this delete.  The location of the files are as follows:

```
http://ipaddress/dataconf/productusers/**ACCOUNT**/presentations/
```

I have access to the ACCOUNT name which is a parameter that will need to be passed in to navigate to the right directory.  I will also have access to the presentation name which will be needed to specify the correct presentation to delete.

What I am having trouble with is where to begin.

I am using the Spring framework so my code is a mixture of Java, JSP, and JavaScript.

Essentially I have a .jsp page where I layout the presentations that are associated with each account.  I.E when you click on an account it makes a call to a database and lists the presentations that are associated with that account.  You can then select individual accounts and delete, or press one delete all button and delete them all.

I currently have it working so that when you delete a presentation in my application, it deletes the appropriate record from the database, but I also need to delete the physical presentation which is the basis for this question.  Just as an FYI, these requests (get presentations from database, remove presentations from database) are all being handled through AJAX and JSON.

I am hoping to learn how to create a connection to the correct server, navigate to the proper directory as specified above, and issue the Linux command "sudo rm file-name" all in the same delete process that I described in the prior paragraph.

If you could point me in the right direction, any help would be much appreciated. Also, if you need any further clarification please feel free to let me know.

Thanks again,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

This will not be easy. Or maybe it will. Please understand first that simply knowing where some files are published on an HTTP server is basically useless in terms of manipulating those files.

So I understand the following: You have your own web application on server A, a database somewhere, and some files located on another web server B. Internally on server B, the files will be in some weird directory e.g. `/var/www/docs/whoknowswhat/somefolder/dataconf/productusers`.

What you need to do is to somehow expose this folder from within server B over the network to your server A. Talk to your admin people. Maybe NFS is an option, or maybe Samba, or SSHFS. Make sure you have write permissions, and also make sure that noone else does.

Once you have mounted the location from B in your server A and it is available to you as some directory `/mnt/serverB/productusers`, then all you have to do is [something like this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/), i.e. `File f = ...; f.delete();`

Comment: Plus 1 for your first two sentences hahaha If you get a chance to review the solution I posted maybe it will help you in your future endeavors as well.  Thank you for your input @Antares42!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and stumbled upon a neat solution to accomplish what I am trying to do. If you take a look at the following link:

http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system

The above site describes a method in which you can open an ssh connection in Java and execute commands as if you were running them from the terminal.  It has come in handy for my problem and I hope that if anyone else is experiencing the same problem that this will help them as well.  Feel free to let me know what you think.

Comment: I have a bit of a bad gut feeling there, security-wise. Maybe I'm just paranoid. Anyway, yet another option could be to implement a tiny web service (like, one PHP page or one servlet) on server B that takes the account and presentation name as parameters and deletes the corresponding file. That would at least protect you from SSH logins running amok. You can then call that web service either via Ajax from the client or from server A. The latter feels safer and could also be triggered by Ajax. So you go ``client -Ajax-> server A -Http-> server B`` ... deleting the file.